# Access HtmlAttribute of TreeView from ButtonClick

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui

I am trying to access a HtmlAttribute from a selected node of a treeview, and I cannot figure out how to get it from a button click.

I am using MVC4 Kendo UI Razor Engine

After I add the child branch I add the html attribute and I want to grab the Selected '`TypeId`' when I click the button to send to another view.

I have tried the below links, but everything I have tried is giving me a null reference when it tries to send the parameter to the controller/action. If I hard code a id like 1 it the click works as expected.:

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-complete-for-asp-net-mvc/treeview/cannot-get-value-of-selected-item-in-treeview.aspx

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-complete-for-asp-net-mvc/treeview/select-selected-node.aspx

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#dataitem

Here is the script:

```
    <script>

        $("#btn").click(function () {
            var treeview = $("#TreeView").data("kendoTreeView");//how to grab the selected idtopass?
            window.location = "@Url.Action("Index","Content")" + "?id=" + idtopass;
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            treeview = $("#TreeView").data("kendoTreeView");
        });
    </script>
```

Edit,

Tried something like this

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
        var treeSelected = $("#TreeView").data("kendoTreeView");
        var idtoPass = treeSelected.dataItem(treeview.select()).Id;//how to grab the selected idtopass?

        window.location = "@Url.Action("Index","Content")" + "?id=" + idtoPass;
    });
```

Here is google Chrome Inspector when I select a child then right click and inspect element

```
<li class="k-item" data-id-to-pass="30" data-uid="151ce59e-97cf-4aed-b8d7-3054c886d68c" role="treeitem" aria-selected="true" id="treeview_tv_active">
    <div class="k-top">
        <span class="k-in k-state-selected">This is the Test Text</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it should be pretty easy given the following demo provided the id is being set in the DOM. Have you checked if that part it working?  I use Chrome and right-click "Inspect element" to view the DOM structure.
http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#methods-select

To get the value using that attribute, in your onSelect method, e.node should give you the DOM node.  I'm guessing your data_id_to_pass attribute is on that node or its parent.  Something like $(e.node).attr("data_id_to_pass") or $(e.node).parent().attr("data_id_to_pass").

If you want to get the selected node from your button click handler, use treeview.select() to get the selected node.

Did you try using the Id property like Alex mentioned in your first link?  That seems like the better approach.  Should be able to do treeview.dataItem(treeview.select()).Id if what he says works for populating the Id property on the dataItem.

Comment: I inspected the elements and for eg. "data-idtopass="26"" Does show up like expected.  That is what I am trying to grab and send to the View.  I will try what you suggested.  Thanks. UpVote for great help.  And yes data_id_to_pass is on the child node

Comment: Using .Id was throwing a null parameter for the action.